# JSF not share session cross tab

Tags: jsf

Now I'm working on JSF web project. I want to use new session when user click on one new tab on browser. That means session will not be shared between different tabs. Does someone have any idea about that? What's kind of solution can help me to forbidden session share in browser tabs? Thanks.

Comment: you can't, the application doesn't know if it's running in two different tabs or if it was just opend/reloaded twice in the same tab.

Comment: I want to user login in the system again when he open one new tab. The previous tab will still work basing on previous session.

Comment: that's not possible, cookies are shared between tabs

Comment: but maybe you can do it with a session token in the url, but I guess you would need to implement the whole sessionscope part yourself and you won't be secured against copying the url from one tab to another.

Comment: Just store data of interest in a viewscoped bean instead and make use of ajax navigation.